# What's the correct way to write this sentence?

Tags: grammar

1. Do people look as fresh as they show in movies in morning?
2. Do people look as fresh in mornings as they show in movies?

Comment: What do you want the sentence to mean? Are you asking about how people look in  movies shown in the morning or how they appear in mornings shown in the movies?

Comment: _Do people really look as fresh in the morning as they do in (the) movies?_ The fixed phrase is _in the morning_, meaning every morning. The article is optional for the generic _movies_. And _show_ is not used that way; _look_ is the correct verb but you've already used it, so use _do_ to stand for it.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's assuming OP's "they" refers back to earlier "people" (who may or may not "look fresh"). But in principle we could choose to understand "they" as referring to *other* people - specifically, *people who make movies*. In which case *Do people really look as fresh in the morning as they [the film-makers] **show them** [actors] **looking / to look** in movies?*